# Performances Issues With Radeon HD 5470

Tags: ati, graphics, video, radeon

I've got a Dell laptop with 4gb ram, intel core 2 duo and a Radeon HD 5470 graphics card, and I'm facing some performances issues.
While watching 720/1080p HD movies there are a lot of bugs and the video stream is not "smooth" as I excepted it to be. 
Considering the hardware I've got, I don't except this laptop to run games but do except it 
to run HD videos properly.

Any idea or suggestion that may point me to the solution will be great,
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a laptop the architecture wil be a lot slower than a desktop equivalent.
Don't forget that 1080p HD is most of the time very heavy to decode.....even for your laptop.

But you can do something about it.

Since your videocard is from the 5000 series of AMD Radeon you have the possibility to let your GPU do a big part of the decoding. If you install the proprietary drivers (like `fglrx-updates` from the standard repository) and you install `mplayer-vaapi` you will have a splendid hardware acceleration on your movies.

Here is an excellent how-to:
http://www.webupd8.org/2012/11/install-mplayer-with-va-api-hardware.html

And if you have trouble installing the proprietary drivers, you can find good info here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI

Even my ultraslow Asus eee netbook can do 1080i now :-) thanks to "vaapi" (google for it)